# Dependency property null

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have created my UserControl with `Owner` property

```
<shared:NavigationControl Owner="{Binding  ElementName=This, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}"  />
```

`This` property is `x:Name` of my Page.

Here is code behind:

```
public MvxWindowsPage Owner
{
    get { return (MvxWindowsPage)GetValue(OwnerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OwnerProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty OwnerProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register("Owner", typeof(MvxWindowsPage), typeof(NavigationControl), null);
```

I have created `TestConverter` to check if binding is ok and it is.

Why `Owner` property is `null` in cs?

Comment: Have you tested This is not null? Show where/how you are setting This.

Comment: Can you show the Converter, what are you returning there? I suspect that the problem is inside the converter - do you have there `return value;` at the end?

Comment: of course i think the problem is that at the value gets binded after window is loaded and i am trying to get the value in my construcor and its before binding might be?

Comment: If you try to get it in the constructor, then sure you will get *null*. You should be able to get the value once the Page with ElementName is Loaded (in that event it should be available also).

Comment: That make sense but is there any event to get value after bind? There is static callback but I cant change UI in this control from static context

Comment: When do you want it to be available? What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Issue most likely is in your `This` property. You will have to confirm that it isn't null. Add a PropertyChanged callback, and then debug and confirm that the value sent to your OwnerProperty isn't null.

```
public MvxWindowsPage Owner
{
    get { return (MvxWindowsPage)GetValue(OwnerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OwnerProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty OwnerProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register("Owner", typeof(MvxWindowsPage), typeof(NavigationControl), new PropertyMetadata(PropChanged));

public static void PropChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
      var value = e.NewValue; //confirm this isn't null
}
```

Comment: e.NewValue contains proper value ;O

Answer (score 0):

As I've checked the problem is that *Binding* is available first in *Loading* event of your page where is the *ElementName* (you are not setting the *DataContext* anywhere). If you want the value to be available in the *Page's* constructor, you will have to invoke bindings update earlier. This can be done with setting *DataContext* which will invoke the process, however there is a simpler way with `x:Bind`:

```
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUsrCtrl" Owner="{x:Bind This, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

then in Page's constructor you can ivoke the binding update like this:

```
public BlankPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Bindings.Update();
    var aaa = myUsrCtrl.Owner; // this shouldn't be null now
    // rest of code
```

Though maybe changing you logic will be better than invoking the update in the constructor.

Comment: Great thank for Yor time. The point is I have this user control which is navigation bar. I wanted to make it visibble on any page in my application. Navigation behaviour is to highlight current viewed page. I thought I can have this navigation bar which current page so I could highlight icon in this navigation bar control

Comment: @miechooy Then I would go for different design. Make your windows content a *Page* with navigation bar at the bottom, and the rest fill with frame which will hold rest of the pages. Then in your navigation bar you can just bind to `Frame.Content` (with some casting if needed).